# Why "return" on PHP function is not stopping the process?

Tags: php, return

I do not understand why "return" is not stopping the process in this function that I created to search a value on a multi_level array in PHP.
This is the code:

```
static function in_array_multi($needle, $haystack) {

            foreach ($haystack as $item) {                
                if(is_array($item)){
                    in_array_multi($needle, $item);
                }
                else{
                    if ($item === $needle) {
                        return "ok";
                    }
                }
            }
            return "nok";    

    }
```

I am using this array as exemple:

```
$arr = array(0 => array(id=>1,name=>"cat 1"),
             1 => array(id=>2,name=>"cat 2"),
             2 => array(id=>3,name=>array(id=>7,name=>"cat 7"))
             );
```

And I am calling the function like this:

```
echo in_array_multi("cat 1",$arr);
```

It is returning "nok".
I am using xdebug to follow the process. It should stop the process on the second round.
Someone has any idea about what is happening? 
Thanks

Comment: You aren't returning when you recur on `in_array_multi`. Change `in_array_multi($needle, $item);` to `return in_array_multi($needle, $item);`

Comment: hello kojiro, your suggestion make the code work, but I think that there is a error in my code. Now the function do not pass through all array. For example, if I look for cat 7. It return nok. Can you see where is the error?

Comment: Hah, yes, sorry – I was a little careless. I created a better answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My comment was a bit careless. You would only want to return directly from the recursion if the recursion actually finds the value. You could do

```
function in_array_multi($needle, $haystack) {
    foreach ($haystack as $item) {                
        if(is_array($item)){
            if ('ok' === in_array_multi($needle, $item)) {
                return 'ok';
            }
        }
        elseif ($item === $needle) {
            return "ok";
        }
    }
    return "nok";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you make the return of function will stop the loop, you should collect it and return in the final.

Maybe you want this..

```
function array_multiple_search($array, $key, $value=null) {
    $return = array();
    if (is_array($array)) {
        if (isset($array[$key])) {
            if (is_null($value)) {
                $return[] = $array;
            } elseif ($array[$key] == $value) {
                $return[] = $array;
            }
        }
        foreach ($array as $subarray) {
            $return = array_merge($return, array_multiple_search($subarray, $key, $value));
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
```

param 1 is the target array

param 2 is the key you want to search of target array

param 3 is the value you want to search with the key of target array(can null)

This function will collect and return an array of qualified.